# Use ssl on top of encrypted overlay network?

Tags: ssl, wireguard

All communication between hosts is already encrypted as they are connected with the Nebula overlay network (or i.e wireguard).
Would you also use ssl encryption between services or plain unencrypted http?

Comment: That entirely depends on your threat model. And you have to define it, because right now this question is asking for opinions rather than fact-based answers and therefore it is off topic on ServerFault.

Comment: It is not uncommon to have encryption within the application layer (message based encryption), and transport layer encryption. As to if it is needed or not depends on your environment.

Answer (score 1):

SSL certificates do not only provide transport encryption, they also provide [(mutual) authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication)  which may be a reason to use them regardless of any network encryption already happening.

A second reason to still use TLS  may be to address the risk of hosts (potentially) communicating in clear text when the VPN has failed.

But as [already commented](https://serverfault.com/questions/1112575/use-ssl-on-top-of-encrypted-overlay-network/1112595#comment1453230_1112575) that depends on your risk analyses and threat model.